# (printenv SHLVL) displays 0

Tags: bash, shell

Can somebody explain the following behavior, please?
GNU bash, version 5.2.21(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

```
$ (echo $SHLVL)
1
$ printenv SHLVL | cat
1
$ (printenv SHLVL)
0
```

I don't understand the last result. Why does (printenv SHLVL) display 0 while (echo $SHLVL) displays 1 (which is expected)? what does it even mean when SHLVL is 0?

Comment: it displays 1 in zsh as expected

Answer (score 1):

`echo` is a bash built-in command.  It is internal to bash itself.  `printenv` is an external command.  It runs in a separate process.  When bash starts a subprocess using `exec`, it decrements the value of SHLVL, since the existing shell will be going away.    If you do `/bin/sh`, for example, you don't see this.

The explanation is here, although this doesn't fully explain the behaviors I see as I play with this.

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2020-10/msg00017.html